# Guetting a subset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 14 columns, and I want to subset a dataframe with the same column but keeping only row that repeats (for example, I have an ID variable and if ID = 2 repeated so I subset it).
To begin, I applied a *table* to my dataframe to see the frequencies of ID

```
head(sort(table(call.dat$IMSI), decreasing = TRUE), 100)
```

In my case, *20801170106338* repeat two time; so I want to see the two observation for this ID.
Afterward, I did `x <- subset(call.dat, IMSI == "20801170106338")` and `hsb6 <- call.dat[call.dat$IMSI == "20801170106338", ]`, but the result is false (for x, it's returning me 0 observation of 14 variale and for hsb6 I have only NA in my dataframe).

Can you help me, thanks.

PS: IMSI is a numeric value.
And `x <- subset(call.dat, Handset.Manufacturer == "LG")` is another example which works perfectly...

Comment: Sorry everyone, the commands didn't work because of my IMSI...(the IMSI was wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use duplicated that is a function giving you an array that is TRUE in case the record is duplicated.

```
isDuplicated <- duplicated(call.dat$IMSI)
```

Then, you can extract all the rows containing a duplicated value.

```
call.dat.duplicated <- all.dat[isDuplicated, ]
```